# Настройка коннектора для Mysql в среде Gradle и Intellij Idea

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, gradle

Добрый день!
Прошу сильно не пинать, первый вопрос на Стаке. :)

Каким образом можно добавить mysql-connector в Intellij Idea, чтобы его можно было прописать в зависимостях Gradle. Не могу понять сам принцип подключения этого коннектора. 
Подозреваю, что в зависимостях Gradle нужно прописать что то типа:

```
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.34'
```

Но куда подключать коннектор? Gradle мне сам же его не установит.

Comment: Конечно установит. [Именно для этого он и нужен](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html).

Comment: В результате удалось установить соединение с mysql - добавив в зависимости название драйвера и добавив jar файл драйвера mysql в Libraries. Пока не могу понять правильно это или нет, но работает.